# Data Access Layer

Tags: data-access-layer

We are building a MVC application and at this stage have tried Fluent Hibernate with Repository pattern. The big problem with this is that we are loading all the data into memory. This will not work for us since there will be millions of records in our tables. We are now trying to find out what other big projects have used for their data access layer which worked. Remember this is using APS.Net MVC. So anybody point out how we can implement a good DAC layer

Comment: why do you need to load all your data into memory? That is what databases are for...

Comment: I am sure you are aware, am just reiterating :), `Lazy Loading` can surely prevent loading unnecessary data into memory.

Comment: Thats the thing Brennan - I dont want to load all the data in memory. The Fluent NHibernate with repository pattern is loading all data in memory at the moment and we dont want that. So thats why I was asking what are some other solutions that people have used

Answer (score 0):

I used LINQ (to MS SQL) in a few projects and the performance is satisfactory. But the biggest table only has about 400,000 records. It converts to parametrized SQL and is supposed to be as fast as stored procedure. Compiled LINQ will speed it up but I've never had to do that.